# Something in the likes of IList.IndexOf() but on IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Is there any method / extension method on IEnumerable that allows me to find the index of of an object instance in it? Like IndexOf() in IList?

```
indexPosition = myEnumerable.IndexOf() ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` is not an ordered set.
Although most IEnumerables are ordered, some (such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet`) are not.

Therefore, LINQ does not have an `IndexOf` method.

However, you can write one yourself:

```
///<summary>Finds the index of the first item matching an expression in an enumerable.</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search.</param>
///<param name="predicate">The expression to test the items against.</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if no items match.</returns>
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

    int retVal = 0;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (predicate(item)) return retVal;
        retVal++;
    }
    return -1;
}
///<summary>Finds the index of the first occurence of an item in an enumerable.</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search.</param>
///<param name="item">The item to find.</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if the item was not found.</returns>
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T item) { return items.FindIndex(i => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, i)); }
```

Comment: Hmm, but if you say it's not an ordered set, shouldn't I then use a IList when I want something that's supposed to be ordered? Seems to me that using IEnumerable to then have to re-implement the wheel is kinda awkward.

Comment: Yes, you should use an `IList<T>`.

Comment: If the fact that `IEnumerable` is not always ordered motivated the absence of an `IndexOf` extension method, then why do we have `ElementAt`?

Answer (score 3):

**Extension Methods for Enumerable Part II - Index injection and index extraction** http://chaowchaow.blogspot.com/2008/05/extension-methods-for-enumerable-part.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that there couldn't be any instance method because `IEnumerable` is covariant.

Anything of type `IEnumerable<string>` has to implement `IndexOf(string x)`, and, due to covariance, can be casted to `IEnumerable<object>`.

So it now exposes as `IndexOf(object x)` what is really `IndexOf(string x)`, and since not all `objects` are `strings`, couldn't work for all objects.

`IList` can do it because it's invariant, i.e. you can't cast an `IList<string>` to an `IList<object>`.